# Azure Storage DTU (Data Throughput Units)

Tags: azure, load, e-commerce

How can I predict how much storage DTU should I allocate as I have my load testing result from load impact or loader.io? Is there any formula or calculation for me to count this prediction? The azure web application was a web services E-Commerce.

Many thanks!

Comment: Your question title states you're using Azure Storage, which equates to blobs, tables, and queues. Is this what you're referring to, or did you mean SQL Database? Azure Storage does not have DTU, while SQL Database does. Note: Even if you're referring to SQL Database, I believe this question is off-topic, as nobody can really answer this - it's going to be specific to your app, based on your load-testing, and there's no easy answer to that.

Comment: yes, i mean the SQL database. sorry for the unclear statement published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from MS actually developed an 'Azure SQL Database DTU Calculator' for this as a side project, you can find it [here](http://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/), and a more detailed explanation [here](https://justinhenriksen.wordpress.com/2015/05/15/introducing-the-azure-sql-database-dtu-calculator/).

Would that be of any help?

Jesse